# Matlab and HDF5: now to write variable length element into an existing dataset

Tags: matlab, hdf5

My goal is to write a matlab cell in a HDF5. I want to write only a subset of my cell at the creation of the file and to write the rest later on. Unfortunately, the high-level HDF5 functions of Matlab cannot handle cells. Therefore I am working with the low-level functions.

So far, I am able to create the file, the dataset and to write subset of my cell. But I am not able to reopen the file to write another subset.

Here is the code that creates the file and writes the two subsets:

```
% create a dummy cell
mycell{1,1} = [1:4];
mycell{2,1} = [2:6]; 
mycell{3,1} = [1:10]; 
mycell{4,1} = [1:3];
dim = size(mycell);  

% create the HDF5 file
file = H5F.create('myfile.h5','H5F_ACC_TRUNC','H5P_DEFAULT','H5P_DEFAULT');
filetype = H5T.vlen_create('H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
space = H5S.create_simple(2,fliplr(dim),[]);
dcpl = H5P.create ('H5P_DATASET_CREATE');
dset = H5D.create(file,dsetName,filetype,space,dcpl);

%write the first subset (from 1 to 2)
memtype = H5T.vlen_create('H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
start  = [1 1];
count  = [2 1];
H5S.select_hyperslab(space,'H5S_SELECT_SET',fliplr(start-1),[1 1],fliplr(count),[1,1]);
H5D.write (dset,memtype,'H5S_ALL',space,'H5P_DEFAULT', mycell);

%write the second subset (from 3 to 3, hence one element)
start  = [3 1];
count  = [1 1];
H5S.select_hyperslab(space,'H5S_SELECT_SET',fliplr(start-1),[1 1],fliplr(count),[1,1]);
H5D.write (dset,memtype,'H5S_ALL',space,'H5P_DEFAULT', mycell);

% close ressources
H5D.close(dset);
H5S.close(space);
H5T.close(filetype);
H5T.close(memtype);
H5F.close(file);
```

Now I want write the last subset in the existing file:

```
% some data
mycell{1,1} = [1:4];
mycell{2,1} = [2:6]; 
mycell{3,1} = [1:10]; 
mycell{4,1} = [1:3];

% open the file
file = H5F.open('myfile.h5','H5F_ACC_RDWR','H5P_DEFAULT');
dset = H5D.open(file,'foo');
space = H5D.get_space(dset);
memtype = H5T.vlen_create('H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE');
start  = [4 1];
count  = [1 1];
H5S.select_hyperslab(space,'H5S_SELECT_SET',fliplr(start), [1,1],fliplr(count),[1,1]);

% write the data
H5D.write(dset,memtype,'H5S_ALL',space,'H5P_DEFAULT',mycell);
```

Unfortunately, the last line fails with the following error:

```
Error using hdf5lib2
The memory space selection is invalid.

Error in H5D.write (line 71)
H5ML.hdf5lib2('H5Dwrite', varargin{:});
```

Any idea how to fix the memory space issue?

Thanks,
Sylv

Comment: Did you just forgot to subtract 1 from `start` when you selected the hyperslab for the last write?